# Perform a cornerRadius and constraint animation at the same time

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I want to animate a recording button, when not recording, it's a big red circle, but when it is recording, it becomes a smaller rectangle with smaller rounded corners.

I perform the animation as such:

```
buttonWidthConstraint.constant = isRecording ? 33 : 66
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    self.innerButtonView.layer.cornerRadius = self.isRecording ? 3 : 33
    self.innerButtonView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The red view is `innerButtonView`, which is pinned with constraints, and it has a widthconstraint where I change the `constant`.

But the animation looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I don't know if it's relevant, but I also don't see the 3px corner radius when it's small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the lack of animation is also described [here](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout/issues/82#issuecomment-132673243).
They fixed it by using

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

instead of

```
self.innerButtonView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I would also suggest trying Sandeep Bhandari's answer.